# Filter drop down menu in SO is too excited to open

Tags: bug, new-nav

The filters' little drop down menu in SO is opening too much!

[image: picture]

Clicking this area after clicking on the `.youarehere` element opens the `.menu-switcher`.

This is terrible.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've seen this bug being reported before but I can't find it as it might be buried on one of the beta-test questions as an answer.